# cakePHP 3.0 one to many relation

Tags: mysql, cakephp, many-to-many, one-to-many, cakephp-3.0

I have a projects table and an images' table.

A project has many images, so it's a one to many relationship between the two tables.

In the images view I can retrieve the project name that is related to an image by using:

```
<?= $image->has('project') ? $this->Html->link($image->project->project_title, ['controller' => 'Projects', 'action' => 'view', $image->project->project_id]) : '' ?>
```

But now I want to do the same for the project view. I want to display all the images related to a specific project. But this doesn't work:

```
<?= $project->has('image') ? $this->Html->link($project->image->image_path, ['controller' => 'Images', 'action' => 'view', $project->image->image_path]) : '' ?>
```

Or do I need a many to many relation for this?

Comment: You only need belongsTo & hasMany. Project hasMany Images & Images belongsTo Projects

Comment: It would be nice if you'd add the solution as an actual answer and accept it later on, so that the question appears as solved to other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution***

In the ProjectsTable:

```
$this->hasMany('Images', [
   'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
   'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

In the ProjectsController:

```
 $project = $this->Projects->get($id, [
   'contain' => ['Categories', 'Users', 'Tags', 'Images']
 ]);
```

In the Projects > view.ctp

```
<?php foreach ($project->images as $images): ?>
   <p><?= h($images->image_path) ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```